# Postgres - Remove NULL values from a json array

Tags: postgresql

I'm building a JSON ARRAY from a table which has a JSON column and non-JSON columns.

Here is my sample data and query:

```
create table check_details(SHORT_NAME VARCHAR, UNIQUE_NO JSON,STATUS VARCHAR);

insert into check_details values('Anu','{"ID":"1e699-76af2"}','REJECTED');

select json_agg(json_strip_nulls(
json_build_object('Name',SHORT_NAME,
'IDS',
jsonb_build_array(case SIGN(position('ACCEPTED' in STATUS) ) when 1 then UNIQUE_NO::jsonb->>'ID' else json_typeof(NULL::json) end) 
)))
from check_details;
```

I am getting this result:

```
[{"Name":"Anu","IDS":[null]}]
```

But I do not want to get "IDS":[null] part in my result when the value of the key IDS is NULL.
How can I achieve this result:

```
[{"Name":"Anu"}]
```

When IDS has a valid value, it has to be an array. Hence using jsonb_build_array.

Comment: what is your postgres version

Comment: I'm using version11.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are placing the result of your CASE statement in a JSON array, so it's a non-empty array containing a JSON null rather than null JSON value.

So you would need to stop that being an array if you want the NULL to be stripped:

```
SELECT
  json_strip_nulls(
    json_build_object(
      'Name',
      short_name,
      'IDS',
      CASE SIGN(position('ACCEPTED' IN status) )
        WHEN 1 THEN (unique_no::jsonb->>'ID')::text
        ELSE NULL
      END
    )
  )
FROM
  check_details;

 json_strip_nulls 
------------------
 {"Name":"Anu"}
(1 row)
```

Note that json_strip_nulls() doesn't remove null values from JSON arrays.

Edit:
But as you require non-null values to show as an array, move the jsonb_build_array() function into the case statement

```
SELECT
  json_strip_nulls(
    json_build_object(
      'Name',
      short_name,
      'IDS',
      CASE SIGN(position('ACCEPTED' IN status) )
        WHEN 1 THEN jsonb_build_array((unique_no::jsonb->>'ID')::text)
        ELSE NULL
      END
    )
  )
FROM
  check_details;
```

Comment: It has to be an array when it has a valid value because that is how the downstream system expects it.

Comment: Understood.  I've updated my answer with a way to put non-null values into an array, otherwise it isn't output.